# Count IF MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

eu tenho uma tabela que tem um campo ID.

```
ID
1234
1234
1235
1235
1235
1236
```

E gostaria de obter via query o seguinte resultado:

```
ID  ID_Counter
1234    2
1234    2
1235    3
1235    3
1235    3
1236    1
```

Onde na segunda coluna o valor do campo seria a quantidade de vezes que o ID daquela linha aparece na coluna de ID.

Tentei a query: `select ID, Count(ID) from tabela group by ID`, mas o resultado fica:

```
ID  ID_Counter
1234    2
1235    3
1236    1
```

Seria tipo um `cont.se()` do Microsoft Excel, mas não estou sabendo criar a query no MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Mas qual a lógica disso ? O resultado que você obteve é o correto!

Comment: A query está certa... o quê exatamente está faltando?

Comment: É que cada linha desse banco é uma interação de um consultor com o cliente, então para não perder informação preciso que todas as linhas apareçam e também preciso de um contador para eventuais filtros nos relatórios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das soluções para o seu problema é usando uma SubQuery para mostrar a quantidade de registros, no caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id, 
       (SELECT Count(id) 
        FROM   tabela t1 
        WHERE  t1.id = t2.id 
        GROUP  BY id) AS Count 
FROM   tabela t 
GROUP  BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma Solução que resolve, mas menos elegante seria fazer uma subquery:

```
SELECT t.ID,sub.contador FROM tabela as t
 INNER JOIN (select ID, Count(ID) contador from tabela group by ID) as sub
 ON sub.ID = t.ID
```

É uma solução mais imediativa.